# Mac preview vs Adobe acrobat reader DC

Tags: pdflatex, adobe-reader, hyperref

I had this question after [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316020/61047) discussion. The problem is Mac Preview behaves differently than Adobe acrobat reader DC. The pdf is compile with pdflatex. Here is MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={main.pdf},
    colorlinks=false,
    linkbordercolor=red
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

 \section{test}

 \section{test2}

  This is testing hyperref

\end{document}
```

and the results in preview and Adobe acrobat reader are

[image]

and

[image]

respectively. This also looks perfectly alright in the internal viewer of my editor (texstudio).

Que: why can't I see red boundaries in preview?

Comment: I see a statement of things looking different, but I do not understand what question you are asking.

Comment: Question added....